# Mobile Silverlight Applications

Tags: silverlight, mobile

Have You got any tutorials, books, any good resources to start creating mobile games using silverlight ?

Maybe any good resource on writing 2d games in silverlight for  pc?

Ay way do You think that its worth learning it or any other technology would be better and have probably shinier future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Windows 7 Phone SDK if you are interested in Silverlight for mobile.

- http://developer.windowsphone.com/
- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cabcd5ed-7dfc-4731-9d7e-3220603cad14

.  If you're doing simple games, then silverlight might be ok, but if you're serious about building games for mobile, look into XNA Studio. It will be the gaming sdk for mobile 7.  It also will run on xbox and pc. To get started, watch the videos from MIX

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/17/videos-of-mix10-windows-phone-sessions.aspx